# Can i use $stateParams if i do not have key value pair objects in my response that i am returning?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angular-ui-router, state

What I mean is let's say you have an array of objects. They are all the same. They have an id, they have the city name, and country name as keys and their value will be say 1, NYC, USA. Now if i wanted to click on the NYC picture and take me to the data specific to NYC, I would do a:

```
ui-sref = "insert_state_ i_ want_ to_ go ({id: x.id})"
```

provided that x is the name of the ng-repeated object. Then in the app obviously in the url you would include the :id placeholder. Then you would need to inject $stateParams in the service file. Then run a for loop and write an if else statement checking 
`if ($stateParams.id === response.data[i])` etc. 
get the point? But what if I have an array of pictures. No key value pairs. But I want to click on one picture and it takes me to the next state with that same picture enlarged. Do I convert the array into an array of objects? what is the solution? Thanks for the help.

My array looks like this:                          `["119306.jpg","149426.jpg","157715.jpg","161706.jpg","171278.jpg","172313.jpg","179934.jpg","182047.jpg","182084.jpg","182261.jpg","183351.jpg","185276.jpg","189666.jpg","190304.jpg","191798.jpg","191974.jpg","192231.jpg","194943.jpg","196365.jpg","196596.jpg"]`
I have ng-repeated all this pictures in my homebody state. In the homebody state there is a ui-sref that would take me to the productview state (where I want the pictures enlarged). My states look like this:

```
.state('homebody', {
    url:'/',
    templateUrl: '../homebody.html',
    controller: 'homebodyCtrl'
})

.state('productview', {
    url:'/productview/:id',
    templateUrl: '../productview.html',
    controller: 'productviewCtrl'
})
```

Comment: Please provide some code context how you are using this array and sample of routing config

Comment: I have edited to include the code context above.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to go through formatting help and try formatting the question so it is readable. Properly indent code and put it in code blocks. Paragraphs would also help

Comment: sorry i tried....